# Is there a way to remove close button from another process with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I tried it with C++ and it seems like one needs to inject code into another process to disable its main window's close button. But I'm curious, since I actually need it for a .NET program, can I gray out its main window's close button with C#?

PS. Again the process that I'm doing it for is not mine. I can find it as such:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    IntPtr pFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;

    //Now how to disable it's close button?
}
```

Comment: @Sysyphus: Nevermind. I got it done with WinAPIs.

Answer (score 6):

I think I got it:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);


const uint SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;

Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    IntPtr pFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;

    IntPtr nSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(pFoundWindow, false);
    if (nSysMenu != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        if (DeleteMenu(nSysMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND))
        {
            //Done!
        }
    }
}
```